# media query does not behave as intended when margin is added

Tags: css, media-queries, margins

I am trying to add a 10px margin between the boxes and retain their intended media query values. But when it's added, the third box is pushed to the second row, I believe it is adding more pixels to the width of the box but I don't know how to make it scale automatically.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.titles {
 float:right;
 border-left: solid;
 border-bottom: solid;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
} 

.borders {
 border-style: solid;
 float: left;
}

p {
 margin:15px;
 margin-top:35px;
} 

@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .p1 {
  width:33.33%;
 }
 .p2 {
  width:33.33%;
 }
 .p3 {
  width:33.33%;
 }
}
```

```html
<html lang="zxx">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="module2.css">
    <title>Module2-Solution</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Module 2 Assignment</h1>
    <div class="p1 borders">
      <div class="titles">One</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="p2 borders">
      <div class="titles">Two</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="p3 borders">
      <div class="titles">Three</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.</p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want some space between the boxes on a wide screen, all you need to do is decrease their widths a bit.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.titles {
  float: right;
  border-left: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.borders {
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
}

p {
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .p1 {
    width: calc(33.33% - 7px);
  }
  .p2 {
    width: calc(33.33% - 7px);
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  .p3 {
    width: calc(33.33% - 7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Module 2 Assignment</h1>
<div class="p1 borders">
  <div class="titles">One</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.</p>
</div>

<div class="p2 borders">
  <div class="titles">Two</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.</p>
</div>

<div class="p3 borders">
  <div class="titles">Three</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.</p>
</div>
```

But it could be I'm misunderstanding your question; if so, let me know!

Comment: Note that Temani Afif's answerr (which I saw only after I posted this) is probably the better choice, but I'll leave this up as an alternative.